# For elastic collisions, can I transfer mass to velocity?

Tags: momentum, collision

I think my teacher said that because the momentum is the same if you multiply/divide mass and velocity by the same factor, you can make the masses equal and then do a shortcut. Is this right?

Comment: A few things are unclear here. The momentum is the same as what? What are "the masses" here? A little more elaboration would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Lets say we have a 1kg object at 5 m/s and a 2 kg object at 4m/s. Can you basically say the second object is a 1kg object at 8 m/s? The momentum of the second object before and after the change is the same. Is this a valid approach to problem solving?

Answer (score 0):

In an elastic collision, kinetic energy is conserved. That is, for a system of $N$ particles,
$$\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{2}m_jv_{i_j}^2=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{2}m_jv_{o_j}^2$$
where $v_i$ denotes initial velocity and $v_o$ denotes final velocity. This is incredibly useful when it comes to calculating the final velocities of the objects.

In the case of an object $k$ where $m_k=2\text{ kg}$ and $v_{i_k}=4\text{ m/s}$, then the initial kinetic energy is 16 Joules. However, if you were to change that to $m_k=1\text{ kg}$ and $v_{i_k}=8\text{ m/s}$, then the initial kinetic energy is 32 Joules. That will get you an incorrect answer.

So no, you cannot use this method. You will get the same initial momenta, but different initial kinetic energies.

Comment: What if you don't use energy? Only momentum?

Comment: @EvanAdler Things still won't work, because the final momentum won't be the same, because you've altered the mass of the object.